# Generate icons, and its properties, dynamically using controllers

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I'm using angularJs 1.3 with Angular Material Design 0.8.3 and I have a page that has a toolbar on the top `<md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-glow-z2 md-default-theme">` where I'm trying to put some icons dynamically. The page has some crud's and each crud has it own controller. The case is, each crud must have it specific icons at the toolbar, I'm trying to specify it through the controllers but I have no idea how can I write this cuz each icon should have it owns properties (the href link, the action function etc). Someone know if its possible to apply this idea (control the icons that will appears in the screen per crud via controllers)?

Comment: CRUD means Create, Read, Update, Delete. Basically I have screens like "Users", and I need to have, for example, an 'add user' icon at top at the page, but this icon must appears only in the User's crud screen for the other screens the icon (or icons) must be different (specific for that screen).

Comment: use something like font-awesome and dynamically apply classes with ng-class.

Comment: this way you suggest @tpie I will need put all icons in the index page, right?

Comment: it's difficult to help because you have given no code and not much detail.
Are you using a single template that you need to be dynamic?  Are you loading different views for each 'crud'?

Comment: post your html at least, and a plunker would be better.

Comment: The way I was saying, you put one <I> tag and use ng-class to determine which icon to display, perhaps based on location.

Comment: 'crud' is not a descriptive enough term for a single item. It's like calling a chair 'a furniture'. As per your problem, @tpie 's suggestion of changing an icon class `<i class="{{someClass}}"></i>` is a good one.